# No file or directory found at mp_hand_gesture

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, pip, mediapipe

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import mediapipe as mp
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

I have these imports in my code, i installed mediapipe and tensorflow and when I run my code I get this message
"OSError: No file or directory found at mp_hand_gesture
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.  "

Anyone faced this issue before and how was it solved?

Comment: you need to show us the entire code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22No+file+or+directory+found+at+mp_hand_gesture%22) I found this article: https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/hand-gesture-recognition-tensorflow-opencv/ It has this download link:

Please download the source code of hand gesture recognition project: [Hand Gesture Recognition ML Project Code](https://techvidvan.s3.amazonaws.com/machine-learning-projects/hand-gesture-recognition-code.zip). Unzip the archive and the directory `mp_hand_gesture` is there.